# Redirect parked domain to main domain with parameter

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to make a simple url shortening service. I've two domains, one is parked (x.co) another is main (maindomain.com) domain. I want to make a redirection for parked domain in htaccess like this:

http://x.co/abc
will be redirected to:
http://maindomain.com/redirect.php?code=abc

I've tried a lot of different rules but none of them worked. For example, I've tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x.co$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://maindomain.com/redirect.php?code=$1 [R=301,L]
```

So, can anyone help me? Thanks...

Comment: Your rule looks fine.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I think so, but it's not working :) It's just redirect x.co to maindomain.com/redirect.php. If I append any char to parked domain like x.co/a, it's redirecting to maindomain.com/a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule in document root of `x.co`:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^x\.co$ [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ http://maindomain.com/redirect.php?code=%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't work. I mean, x.co is successfully redirected to maindomain.com/redirect.php but when I add some path, it's not redirecting. Should I add something else, like "RewriteEngine On" etc.

Comment: Yes definitely `RewriteEngine On` is required before this rule.